# Show if $S \subset \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$ and $(S,+)$ finitely generated then $S \subset R_d$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification

Show if $S \subset \mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$ (as a subring) and $(S,+)$ finitely generated then $S \subset R_d$.

$R_d={\alpha + \beta\omega}$ where $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{Z}$, $\omega=\frac{1+\sqrt{d}}{2}$ if $d \sim 1mod4$ and $\sqrt{d}$ otherwise, $d$ is square free.

Comment: Sorry, what is $R_d$?

Comment: Edited; sorry I'm new to studying algebra and its never clear what's taken for granted and what isntt.

Comment: In general, to define a homomorphism from a finitely generated stuff, you have to do two things: define the homomorphism on the generators, and then show that the relations among generators are satisfied! In this case you are lucky, because a finitely generated subring of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$ is *freely* generated (no relationships between them).

Beside this, you are not hinting at the problem :( the two maps you have defined from S and from $R_d$ have no relationship betwwn them, so you cant conclude by correspondence theorem! This one has to be used with a single map.

Comment: so I have to start from $\phi$ to be from $Q \times Q \rightarrow Q[\sqrt{d}]$? Then I think I can modify it to work from that.

Comment: Nevermind; none of that seems to help me. I've been stuck here for a while. How should I start?

Comment: it depends a bit: how much theory do you know? The key fact here is that the integral closure of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{d}]$ is precisely $R_d$. The other key fact you have to use is that $S$ is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Z}$, and in general a finite extension of rings is integral (see the answer by whatsUp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a lemma in the beginning of algebraic number theory.

Let $\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ be a finite set of generators of $(S, +)$, which exists by assumption.

Let $x$ be any element of $S$. For every $i$, the product $x\cdot x_i$ is in $S$, so there exists integers $a_{ij}$ such that $x\cdot x_i = \sum_j a_{ij} x_j$.

We may write this in matrix form: $$\begin{pmatrix}x\cdot x_1\\\vdots\\x\cdot x_n\end{pmatrix} = A\cdot \begin{pmatrix}x_1\\ \vdots\\ x_n\end{pmatrix},$$ where $A$ denotes the matrix $(a_{ij})_{ij}$.

Now if $p(T) \in \Bbb Z[T]$ is any polynomial, we easily get: $$\begin{pmatrix} p(x)\cdot x_1\\ \vdots \\p(x) \cdot x_n\end{pmatrix} = p(A) \cdot \begin{pmatrix}x_1\\ \vdots\\ x_n\end{pmatrix}.$$ To deduce this, first prove it for $p(T) = T^k$ by induction on $k$, then note that every polynomial is a $\Bbb Z$-linear combination of some $T^k$.

In particular, if we choose $p$ to be the characteristic polynomial of $A$, then we get $p(x) \cdot x_i = 0$ for all $i$, since $p(A) = 0$ by Cayley–Hamilton.

However, the element $1\in S$ is a $\Bbb Z$-linear combination of the $x_i$, thus we have $p(x) = p(x) \cdot 1 = 0$.

Therefore $x$ is the root of a polynomial with integer coefficients and leading coefficient $1$. Namely, $x$ is an algebraic integer.

It is then easy to see that $x$ belongs to $R_d$, as the latter is exactly the ring of algebraic integers in $\Bbb Q[\sqrt d]$.

Comment: ''Let x be any element of S. For every i, the product x⋅xi is in S, so there exists integers aij such that $x⋅x_i=∑jaijxj''. Can you provide any intuition on how you thought to write this? All I really needed was that statement and the rest was just linear algebra, but I don't think in a million years I would think to do that...

Comment: This is a standard proof that you can find on many textbooks, so it's not me who first got this idea...